# LaunchUriAsync with split screen not working in Windows 10

Tags: windows

Using the ViewSizePreference.UseHalf works great for a Windows 8.1 app running in Windows 8.1. However, when I run the same app on Windows 10, I don't get the split screen effect. I guess that may be expected behavior as the UI is quite different, but wondering if there is any kind of workaround for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Split screen launching (that is, ViewSizePreference.UseHalf) is only supported in tablet mode.

Comment: In tablet mode on Windows 10, the app is still launched full screen, not half the screen like the behavior on Windows 8. Would this be considered a bug at this point?